# Date minus date is not giving desired answer - IONIC 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

When I try to subtract

`Wed Dec 06 2017 15:58:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`  minus `Tue Nov 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`  , the answer which is coming is **-22**

But the answer should be **6**

What is going wrong and where, below is my `page.ts` code:

```
  this.tt = new Date();
  this.tt1 = this.datePipe.transform(this.tt,'dd/mm/yyyy');

  console.log(this.ent[0],"server DATE");
  // in console we see this - 28-NOV-17 server DATE

  var firstDate= new Date(this.ent[0]);  //Jan 01 2017 00:00:00

  var secondDate = new Date();//Jan 04 2017 00:00:00

  console.log(firstDate); 
 // answer in console - Tue Nov 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

  console.log(secondDate);
 //answer in console - Wed Dec 06 2017 15:58:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

  console.log(secondDate.getDate() - firstDate.getDate() );
 //answer in console -  -22
```

Comment: Please avoid using the word "requirement" in your questions, since StackOverflow is not a site to make *requirements* but a place to get some help and learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Date.getDate() gives the "dd" of the date (in your case 6 and 28 which explains the result being -22).
I'm a bit confused with the expected result being 6. So maybe my answer won't fit you. What I would do however is convert the date in time, do the substraction and convert it back to number of days.

So

```
Math.Floor((secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime()) / 86400000);

(86400000 being 1000 (milliseconds) * 3600 (seconds in an hour) * 24 (number of hours in a day)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert both dates to timestamp and subtract the timestamp you will get the result days in millis now convert it to days

```
getTimestamp(dateParam:string):string{
    var date = new Date(dateParam); // some mock date
    var milliseconds = date.getTime(); 
    return milliseconds.toString();
} 

var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
console.log(Math.ceil(getTimestamp(secondDate) - getTimestamp(firstDate))/(one_day) );
```